# How can i get http requests in python 3 and have the program sort the status codes

Tags: python, python-3.x, networking, http-headers, http-status-codes

I have a list of cidr notations and i have a python program that generates a list of ip adress from the cidr notation.Here is the program

```
from netaddr import IPNetwork

for ip in IPNetwork('104.24.0.0/6'):

    print ('%s' % ip)
```

But i want to make the program loop through each of the ip adress and send http requests then search for some specific status code and if it finds the required status code it should return which ip adress has that status code

Comment: What's your question? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
import requests
from netaddr import IPNetwork

required_status_code = 200  # your required status code goes here

for ip in IPNetwork('104.24.0.0/6'):
    resp = requests.get(f'http://{ip}')
    if resp.status_code == requires_status_code:
        print (f'ip {ip} matches required status code!')
```